# Reference Test using FsCheck always do not work

Tags: c#, fscheck

I have some trouble of using `FsCheck` on C#. C# version is 7.0.

When using `Fscheck`, arguments behave as if they have same value when they are set to other object.

Please see the code below.

```C#
[Property]
public Property CorrectTest(int x, int y)
{
    return ( x == y ).ToProperty();
}

[Property]
public Property WrongTest(double x, double y)
{
    Values values = new Values();
    SetMethod(values, x, y);

    // "True" is always shown
    return ( Double.Equals(values.x, values.y) ).ToProperty();
}

public struct Values
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
}

private void SetMethod(Values values, double x, double y)
{
    values.x = x;
    values.y = y;
}
```

if I perform `CorrectTest`, the test fails because it is not correct that x is always equal to y.

On the other hand, if I perform `WrongTest`, the test always passes.
It is totally wrong, but the test cannnot detect the problems.

If you know about the related information and the solution, could you please teach me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is because `Values` is a struct, i.e. a value type, i.e. the `values` parameter is *copied* when you pass it to `SetMethod`. As a result, the original `values` variable in `WrongTest` never gets modified.

Try inlining `SetMethod`, or passing the `values` by reference (using the `ref` keyword).

Also consider making `Values` an immutable struct with a constructor that takes `x` and `y` and no setters, this makes everything a lot clearer especially for structs.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I understand that `struct` objects are always called by value, so values objects do not change unless `SetMethod` returns `Values` object.